# Is there hard proof for the Curse of Ymir?

Tags: attack-on-titan

As far as I know, the Survey Corps (and other relevant Elderians) learned of the Curse of Ymir (that a titan shifter only has 13 years to live and if not eaten, will die to have his titan power born again with a random Elderian) from the memories of Grisha Jäger, who in turn learned it from the Owl. The Marleyian army seems to be aware of the course as well. Owl probably got his information from the army or the Taybar family.

Now I wonder, is it guaranteed that this information is correct? From a narrative POV I don't believe the author will just wave his hands and say "The curse never really existed, sorry!", but from an POV from within the world, it would make sense that this is misinformation, deliberately given by King Fritz to protect Elderians outside Paradise (so they are not deliberately killed off as long as they can be used).

**I want to know if there is hard proof that the curse is real? This can be witnessing it in the main series or spinoffs** (I didn't really follow AoT - After the Fall so much) **or in interviews with the creators.**

Something ominous, deliberately question-dodging like "Well, the characters got told so." in the interviews would be interesting too. After all, the characters got also told that titans are mankind's enemy, that you die if eaten by a titan, that Paradise Elderians' are devils etc. Information given in AoT through characters cannot be trusted, as we know after all these years :D

Comment: Without going into too much details, the Curse of Ymir is mentionned by Eren Kruger to Grisha, and Eren Yagger has the memories of Eren Kruger, so at least we can be sure that Eren Kruger was not lying

Comment: @Ikaros Did Eren relive through all the memories or were these just exemplary flashbacks? As it currently stands, I believe they didn't had the time to go through all the memories that are available to Eren? I also believe that Owl believed the information, but that doesn't means it's true.

Comment: Their is no way, daughters of Ymir can reproduce if their life were not compressed in 13 years.

Answer (score 3):

I noticed that Grisha Jaeger did not suffer the rapid aging that other titan shifters experience in their later years. There is one major variable however, Grisha didn't use his powers nearly as much as the others, or suffer major injuries very frequently. 
  Aging is caused by the inevitable genetic screw-ups that occur during cell division. The Matter and Energy may com from Paths(whatever they may be). But instructions for building the titan titan bodies and growing back limbs? That comes from the shifter.

Grisha Only used his titan form twice(Getting to the walls and supper with the Reiss family), and he doesn't get major injuries like a soldier(You know, like Eren Kruger) might experience. It would also explain why Grisha slacked off on his mission for 12 years until he heard about some big-ass titan kicking a hole in the wall.

Answer (score 0):

After the manga had ended, it can be concluded that the Curse of Ymir is actually a lie, and no titanshifter actually died from the curse.

Comment: Hi, did the manga reveal this info specifically, or it's more of a conclusion from personal observation? If the manga did reveal this info, could you mention the chapter?